# Creating a dynamic overlay over page still inerts mouse activity

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a form that slides down on click "signin" and slides up on "close". I wanted to have a translucent overlay below the form and above the page that will make rest of the page dark and inert to mouse activity. Here is the markup:

```
<body>
<div id="container" style="position:absolute;with:100%;height:100%">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<form action="#" method="post">Some Form</form>
</div>
```

The CSS for the overlay:

```
#overlay{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#002aff;
opacity:.7;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
display:none;
}
```

I was calling the overlay and the form using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#overlay").slideDown("fast");
    $("div#panel").slideDown("400");

}); 

// Collapse Panel
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#overlay").slideUp("fast");
    $("div#panel").slideUp("300");  
});     

// Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
$("#toggle a").click(function () {
    $("#toggle a").toggle();
});     

});
```

The problem is this has left the rest of my page inert (no mouse activity in terms of links) throughout the page even if the overlay-er is not active. As a solution to this I tried to .addClass() and .remove() to "#overlay" defining the properties in a class. But still this leaves my page not click-able on load or even after the class is removed...any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the z-index rule on click, so it is -1 when the overlay is not happening.

Comment: Thanks..the problem was with the Z index and the #container itself was acting as an invisible layer. Now I am dynamically adding and removing the styles for the container itself. but its working fine the first time...but once its removed its not adding the second time!

Comment: are you sure you are removing the z-index, can you set up a jsfiddle, so i can check out whats going on.

Comment: Have already solved the problem and the key to the problem was a closer look at the z-index. I was adding and removing classes to the div under the #container, but once fiddled along with the z-index i realized the blank overlay is caused by the container itself. So now I'v tweaked the javascript to $("#container").addClass(".foo"), which did the trick.

Thanks anyway for triggering the spark..would not have realized my stupidity otherwise. Thanks again!!